# Left join not returning all the rows from the left table codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Actually found a lot of question like this before posting but doesn't find one related with "Codeigniter" so I don't know how to implement those answer with codeigniter.

My **meta_key** table

```
key_id | key_name | key_parent
------------------------------
.....1..firstname........1

.....2..lastname.........1
```

My **users_meta** table

```
meta_id | meta_user_id | meta_key_id |meta_value |
--------------------------------------------------
1.........1..............1............chuck......
```

When I run this query

```
$this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("meta_key");
    $this->db->join("users_meta", "users_meta.meta_key_id=meta_key.key_id","left");
    $this->db->where('users_meta.meta_user_id', '1');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query;
```

It always return me single rows ( that is the firstname rows )

Instead of "left" join I tried every option ( Options are: left, right, outer, inner, left outer, and right outer ) from the codeigniter reference page but it still return single rows.

How can I make it to return the "surname" rows as well ?

Comment: I'm guessing it's not about your left join but about your where clause.

Comment: @FlorianF. How else I should use the where clause here?

Comment: just guess and try `$this->db->where('users_meta.meta_user_id = 1 OR users_meta.meta_key_id IS NULL');`

Comment: @cjmling - *(As Mark has deleted his answer)* If the `key_parent` column refers to the parent `key_id`, his answer was correct. If it doesn't, how is the row with `key_id`2 linked to it's *parent* with `key_id`1?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers : they are link to each other as I use in the join statement "users_meta.meta_key_id=meta_key.key_id"

Comment: @GBD : This actually solve my problem, Thanks Alot :). how could I accept answer now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you commented that following code works for you so here it is as answer

```
//just guess and try 
$this->db->where('users_meta.meta_user_id = 1 OR users_meta.meta_key_id IS NULL');
```